# Lamentablemente la app se detuvo problema con imageview Android kit kat (API 19)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, java-8

Buen día coders. Les comento que me sucede.

Estoy haciendo una app para android, nativo, pero al intentar insertar un imageview (tal como lo indica la documentación oficial https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView  api level 16)... la app funciona en dispositivos lollipop 5.0 en adelante (api 20).

sin embargo, en la api 19 (kitkat android 4.4.2) la aplicación se detiene.

**LO UNICO QUE TIENE LA VISTA ES UN IMAGEVIEW, NADA MÁS**, no hay nada programado, solo la activty, con el image view, estoy insertando una imagen PNG de 90x90 pixeles, no debería haber problema alguno.

Al crear la aplicación la puse con la api 16, (la de compatibilidad > 90.5% de los dispositivos android)

acá el código:

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/logo"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
```

como dije, es lo único que tiene el activity, está fresca la app, lo curioso es que con los demás elementos si funciona (TextView, Botton, editText, etc.), pero un activity con un solo imageview se me detiene, la app deja de funcionar.

Probé tanto en el emulador, como en mi samsung galaxy tab 3.0 SMT-210 y nada, en ambos se detiene.

acá el informe del logcat:

```
12-21 15:31:17.041 4007-4007/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: apps.nelingenieria.com.app, PID: 4007
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{apps.nelingenieria.com.app/apps.nelingenieria.com.app.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at apps.nelingenieria.com.app.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060056 a=-1 r=0x7f060056}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2073)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at apps.nelingenieria.com.app.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
12-21 15:31:17.041 1695-2156/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity apps.nelingenieria.com.app/.LoginActivity
```

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano para una posible solución... ya intenté poniendo esto en el AndroidMainfest y no funcionó `android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: Buenas tardes @arxzel , según estuve revisando creo que las dos respuestas mas votadas en esta pregunta podrían ser de ayuda en tu pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621934/inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflating-class-imageview te recomiendo que te fijes si tu imagen se creo en la carpeta correspondiente como indican el las repuesta sea esta drawable-v24 o drawable-v23 o en primera instancia probar con otra imagen a ver si genera el mismo error

Comment: Ya econtré la solución y es mas simple de lo que parece, resulta que en las APIs viejas, el directorio drawable-24 no existe, lo que se debe hacer es mover las imágenes a la carpeta drawable, y ya está. Muchas gracias por tu entusiasmo y ayuda :D

Comment: genial, podrías agregar una repuesta sobre eso a la pregunta así ayudas a otra persona que se encuentre en el futuro con este problemas

Answer (score 2):

En este caso las imágenes que tratas de cargar en tu ImageView son [Vector Drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources) , por lo tanto debes usar la propiedad `app:srcCompat` en lugar de `android:src`

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
     />
```

Comment: Lo hice, pero no funcionó.

Sin embargo dejar las dos respuestas, puede ser que a alguien más si le sirve esta solución.

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta e interés.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución en el siguiente post después de tanto buscar...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095063/resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-is-not-a-drawable-color-or-path

Resulta que la carpeta drawable-24 no se encuentra disponible o no existe en las APIs viejitas de android. La solución fue copiar la imágen a utilizar en la carpeta drawable también. y ya está problema solucionado :D

Comment: No necesitas realizar esto  para eso se usa la "compatibilidad", usa : app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"

Comment: Lo hice, pero no funcionó :(, sin embargo, servirá para alguien más, gracias por responder